# Moving an XML entry from one file to another

Tags: xml, vbscript, asp-classic

I have an XML file with over 1000 entries.  Each entry has about 18 fields and one of these fields is a date field.  What I need to do is to move the entries to a another XML based on the year within the date field. For example, so that all those entries with a 2018 year are in one XML and all those with a 2019 year are in another XML.

The code I have seems to work but take a while to run, just wondering if there is anything obvious I am missing.  I have cut down the code here so it only shows 4 fields, but the code I am running has 18 fields.

```vb
<%
Dim SourceFile
Set SourceFile = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
If SourceFile.FileExists(Server.MapPath("source.xml")) Then
    Dim TargetFile
    Set TargetFile = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    If TargetFile.FileExists(Server.MapPath("target_2018.xml")) Then
        Set SourceXml = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
        SourceXml.Async = "False"
        SourceXml.Load Server.MapPath("source.xml")
        Set colNodes = SourceXml.selectNodes ("//person")
        For Each objSite In colNodes
            Field1 = objSite.SelectSingleNode("Field1").text
            Field2 = objSite.SelectSingleNode("Field2").text
            Field3 = objSite.SelectSingleNode("Field3").text
            Field4 = objSite.SelectSingleNode("Field4").text
            'FIND THE MATCHING RECORD IN THE SOURCE XML AND REMOVE IT.
            'FIELD4 IS A DATE, MATCHING CRITERIA IS THE YEAR.
            Dim strLast: strLast = Right(Field4, 4)
            If strLast = "2018" Then
                objSite.ParentNode.RemoveChild(objSite)

                i = 1
                Set TargetXml = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0") 
                TargetXml.Async = False 
                TargetXml.Load Server.MapPath("target_2018.xml")
                Dim xmlProduct
                Dim CurrentHighestId
                Dim CurrentEntryId
                CurrentHighestId = 1
                For Each xmlProduct In TargetXml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("person")
                    CurrentEntryId = xmlProduct.SelectSingleNode("Entryid").Text
                    If CurrentEntryId >= CurrentHighestId Then
                        CurrentHighestId = CurrentEntryId + 1
                    End If
                    i = i + 1
                Next

                Dim Entryid
                Entryid = CurrentHighestId

                Dim root
                Set root = TargetXml.DocumentElement
                Set newperson = TargetXml.CreateNode("element", "person", "")
                Dim newtextbox0
                Dim newtextbox1
                Dim newtextbox2
                Dim newtextbox3
                Set newtextbox0 = TargetXml.CreateNode("element", "Field1", "")
                Set newtextbox1 = TargetXml.CreateNode("element", "Field2", "")
                Set newtextbox2 = TargetXml.CreateNode("element", "Field3", "") 
                Set newtextbox3 = TargetXml.CreateNode("element", "field4", "")
                newtextbox0.Text = Entryid
                newtextbox1.Text = Field2
                newtextbox2.Text = Field3
                newtextbox3.Text = Field4
                newperson.AppendChild(newtextbox0)
                newperson.AppendChild(newtextbox1)
                newperson.AppendChild(newtextbox2)
                newperson.AppendChild(newtextbox3)
                root.AppendChild(newperson)
                TargetXml.Save(Server.Mappath("target_2018.xml"))
            Else
            End If

            SourceXml.Save Server.MapPath("source.xml")
        Next
    Else
        Message = "Error - Target file can not be found."
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("<%=Message%>");
</script>
<%
    End If
Else
    Message = "Error - Source file can not be found." %>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("<%=Message%>");
</script>
<%
End If
%>
```

Comment: Don't re-open `target_2018.xml` for every node from your source file. Also, use `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0`, not `Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Ansgar. I have amended my code but still takes the same amount of time.  Think that is purely the amount of data its sorting through rather than any actual problems.  Not having done this sort of thing I am unsure as to how long it should actually take but it does the job it needs to so I'm happy.